# Why do we pass null to XMLHttpRequest.send?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Why is `send` so often called as

```
xhr.send(null)
```

instead of

```
xhr.send()
```

?

[W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send()-method), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#send()), and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536736(v=vs.85).aspx) all state that it's optional. Furthermore, the ActiveX control [doesn't seem to need the argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms759148(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
hr=pIXMLHTTPRequest.CreateInstance("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
SUCCEEDED(hr) ? 0 : throw hr;

hr=pIXMLHTTPRequest->open("GET", "http://localhost/books.xml ", false);
SUCCEEDED(hr) ? 0 : throw hr;

hr=pIXMLHTTPRequest->send(); // <-- this line
SUCCEEDED(hr) ? 0 : throw hr;
```

The practice of `send(null)` goes back at least as far as [2005 in Google Maps](http://web.archive.org/web/20050212032837/http://www.google.com/mapfiles/maps.1.js), but being minified, there's no explanation:

```
Y.asynchronousTransform = function (qc, vb, kc, Nc, Ba) {
    if (m.type == 3) return;
    var cc = Y.getCached(kc);
    if (cc) {
        cc.transformToHTML(qc, vb);
        if (Nc) Nc();
        return
    }
    var yc = qa.create(Ba);
    var sa = Xd.create();
    nd('<a href="' + kc.xmlEscape() + '">' + kc.xmlEscape() + "</a>", 0);
    sa.open("GET", kc, true);
    sa.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (sa.readyState == 4) {
            if (yc.isValid()) {
                try {
                    var Db = sa.responseXML;
                    var cc = Y.create(Db);
                    Y.cache(kc, cc);
                    cc.transformToHTML(qc, vb);
                    if (Nc) Nc()
                } catch (b) {}
            }
        }
    };
    sa.send(null)
}
```

Comment: It's just explicitly saying that nothing is being sent to the server after the request headers.

Comment: @PaulS *Why* is it explicitly saying so? Nobody would get confused, and it *is* valid syntax.

Comment: Why do people do `while (i > 0)` when they could do `while (i)`? It's just a style.

Comment: @PaulS ...because `i` could be negative?

Comment: Did you try Googling how to make an Ajax request, every example has .send(null) and I guess old habits die hard, probably fits under this mantra "Don't fix it if it isn't broken"

Comment: @DaveMackintosh I did, but it doesn't appear `null` was **ever necessary**.

Comment: I wasn't saying it is/was, I'm just saying we've all learned from the same pool of information and haven't dropped the habit. I don't *think* there's a technical reason why lol.

Comment: The only reasoning I can think of is in the case where null and empty string can mean different things. Empty string is said to be the default if you do not explicitly enter a value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you'll take a look at an old specification of XMLHttpRequest, it seems like as though the W3C did not require that the parameter be optional at one point, which may have led to people supplying an explicit null value 'just in case'.

(search for 'SHOULD support the send')
http://web.archive.org/web/20060409155734/http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/

Another plausible reason I've come across comes from a translation of a russian page, viewable here: [long Google Translate link](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.archive.org%2Fweb%2F20131005151134%2Fhttp%3A%2F%2Fxhtml.co.il%2Fru%2FjQuery%2F%25D0%25A2%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BF%25D1%258B%2FXMLHttpRequest&edit-text=) (search for 'GET-Request for Version without ActiveX')

> When you send a GET-request for version without ActiveX, you must specify null, otherwise you can not specify any parameters. Will not fail if GET is always specified null:

I have no idea if this is true or not but it seems plausible that if the GET parameters were included in the body, that the body may not have been generated if the data value was 'undefined'.

Unfortunately, I was unable to find anything more conclusive in my search.

Comment: access to russian page is forbidden xhtml.co.il/ru/jQuery/Типы/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Updated the URL with a wayback machine link.

Answer (score 8):

Not adding the `null` would throw an exception in older versions of Firefox.

This behavior existed as [early as 2002](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=128541) and existed [through Firefox 3 (2008)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=836815).

Answer (score 4):

So, if your HTTP request method is **GET**, then the HTTP client sends data to the server simply by appending it to the request URL (as a so called [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)), meaning that the body of the request is going to be **empty** and that's why you need to set the value of that argument to `null`.

However, if your HTTP request method is **POST**, then your request data will be placed into the request body, which will be eventually sent to the server via `send` function.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The XMLHttpRequest.send() method sends the request. If the request is asynchronous (which is the default), this method returns as soon as the request is sent. If the request is synchronous, this method doesn't return until the response has arrived. send() accepts an optional argument for the request body. If the request method is GET or HEAD, the argument is ignored and request body is set to null.

Comment: Please add a link to the documentation from where you copied the above text, and use quote formatting too.