# issue with ajax send() function

Tags: ajax, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lesson 18: Making AJAX Calls</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Lesson 18: Making AJAX Calls - Plain Text Response</h1>
<div>
<h2 id="myHeader">Click the button to call your data</h2>
<input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="getText('test.txt')" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myRequest;
function getText(url)
        {        
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)        
            {        
            myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();        
            }        
            else        
            {        
            myRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");        
            }
        myRequest.open("GET", url, true);
        myRequest.send(null);    
        myRequest.onreadystatechange = getData;        
        }
function getData()        
        {
        var myHeader = document.getElementById("myHeader");
        if (myRequest.readyState ===4)        
            {        
        if (myRequest.status === 200)    
            {
        var text = myRequest.responseText;
        myHeader.firstChild.nodeValue = text;        
            }        
        }        
        }        
        </script>            
        </body>
        </html>
```

This code is from this tutorial: http://www.html.net/tutorials/javascript/lesson18.php

Questions:

what does this mean: myRequest.send(null); what is the difference between it and myRequest.send();?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No difference. .send(null) is mean that you are sending "null" content in request body. .send() is mean that you are sending nothing in request body.
In case of `GET` requst there is no difference, becouse request body is not sending.
In case of `POST` request there will be none difference too.

See this :[Why do we pass null to XMLHttpRequest.send?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123839)