# What does HTTP status code 490 mean?

Tags: java, http, firefox, selenium, http-status-codes

I'm using Firefox with Selenium IDE for testing a Java application. If the session expires and I launch a test, I get this http status code: `490`.

Here is a snippet that illustrates how I get this http status code.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', url, false);

// ...

request.send(null);

if (request.status === 200) {
    // ...
} else {
    alert('Something bad happen!\n(' + request.status + ') ' + request.statusText);
}
```

The alert dialog box shows something like this:

```
 Something bad happen!
 (490) 490
```

Comment: Not sure why you are sending null, sending a blank object (like Document formData etc ) isn't that an option ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#send%28%29

Comment: @Lav I have read dozen of codes with sending null. Check this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123839/why-do-we-pass-null-to-xmlhttprequest-send

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a standard [HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

It could mean anything depending on the implementation of the application you are making this request to.